# On an infinitely sided die, is it possible to roll and get the same number twice?

Tags: probability

In music class, our teacher was saying that every sound we make is uniquely different and has never been heard before. So I kind of thought of a different problem, with the dice. Is there some type of way to calculate the chance? It can’t be zero or can it?

Comment: It depends on the distribution you assign to your die, ie. for each face what is the probability of landing on that face? If it is the same for every face, then the probability is indeed zero.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, such a die does  not exist.

Thus speaking of probability assignment to each event takes us to defining $\frac {1}{\infty} =0$

On the other hand, if probability of some event is zero, it does not mean that it does not happen. Since these events are independent, the next face could as well be the same as the previous one.

Comment: But isn’t a sphere an infinitely sided die? Thx for answering

Comment: Fredbat, if you roll a sphere, how will you determine which "side" the die lands on?

Comment: I dislike the "such a die does not exist".  I always read questions like this "Suppose an infinite sided die existed then ..." mathematics is full of thing that do not exist in the reality (like most of the real numbers).

Comment: @minori minus by points i guess? If you name them a,b etc

Answer (score 2):

I like this question a lot.

So lets say the die is a sphere, with a continuously changing and unique hue on every point of its surface.

The probability of getting a hue in a given range can be calculated by dividing the [solid angle](https://www.schorsch.com/en/kbase/glossary/solid-angle.html) that contains that hue by $4\pi$ (the solid angle of the whole sphere).
In this case we are interested in an infinitesimal solid angle to capture one colour only.

Let's call the 'area' $\delta$ and we will take $\delta \rightarrow 0$ in the end. Let us call the total number of ways the sphere could land (or exact colours) we could obtain $C$ and we will take $C \rightarrow \infty$ in the end.

The number of ways two dice could fall is the product of each individual possibility; $C^2$ (infinite number of possibilities, like in the music example). The number of ways they could fall and have hues in the same area is;

$$ C * \left(C\frac{\delta}{4\pi}\right) $$
That is, the number of ways the first die can land times the number of ways the second die can land times the fraction of positions of the second die that would be the same hue.

So now the probability of getting the same hue on the two dice is the number of same hue outcomes divided by the total possible outcomes;
$$ \left(C * \left(C\frac{\delta}{4\pi}\right)\right)/(C^2)= \frac{\delta}{4\pi} $$

Directly proportional to the area of the die that we consider to be the same hue. As we take $\delta \rightarrow 0$ to require an exact colour match this probability also goes to $0$.

Comment: p.s. would love comments on any mistakes or inaccuracies of this method.

Comment: I have no objection to your answer. However I do think it brings a interesting questions in how to model different possible sounds. First, why should the hue be continuous, and second, why should they be modeled by a 2-sphere?

Comment: @Couchy311 thanks, good question. I think we can force the hue to be continuous because we can make the top go to white, the bottom go to black and a cycle between blue and red round the equator. This should generate a continuous hue, could even have a uniform rate of change. 

Sound is more complicated, with light when two frequencies overlap humans perceive the average, if two notes occur simultaneously we still perceive both notes. Basically we can detect a cord, but not the light equivalent. I'm not sure how to map sounds to the sphere.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you model the die. For instance, following your comment to another question, you might assume that the die is a sphere, and that rolling it means sampling a single point on its surface using a uniform distribution.

If you do so, the probability of landing on a given region of that sphere is given by

$$
\dfrac{\mbox{area of the region}}{\mbox{area of the whole surface}}
$$

Here one should define "area" precisely (and possibly cope with the fact that there might be regions without an area). Let's assume, say, the Lebesgue measure, which feels quite natural.

So, rolling a point on the upper "hemishpere" is $1/2$.

The probability of rolling a single point $x$ is zero, since the area of the set $\{x\}$ is zero.

If we roll twice such die, we are sampling from two independent random variables. The probability of landing on the same point on these rolls is zero.

It's not obvious to visualize this since we are dealing with two 2D surfaces, so two dice make a 4D surface, and the region where they are equal is a 2D subregion of the 4D surface. Let's consider instead an example with lower dimension.

Assume the die is a circle instead. We roll a point on the circumference.
Cut the circumference, and straighten it, so that it becomes an interval $[0,1)$. We can assume that rolling the die gives us a point $0\leq x < 1$ with uniform probablity.

In this scenario, rolling twice the die means choosing a (uniformly) random point in the *square* $S = [0,1)\times [0,1)$, each coordinate of the point $p=(x,y)$ being the result of the individual roll.

The case where the two rolls are equal is the event $E=\{(x,y)\ |\ 0\leq x=y< 1\}$, i.e. the diagonal of the square $S$.

What is the probability of $E$? Well, it is

$$
\dfrac{\mbox{area of }E}{\mbox{area of } S}
$$

Since $E$ is only a line in a square, a one-dimensional object in a two-dimensional space, it has area zero, so the probability of $E$ is zero as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is where we see some of the strange paradoxes that arise when dealing with "infinity" and trying to treat it as a finite number.

If a die (and the singular form of the plural noun "dice" is indeed "die") has *n* sides, numbered 1 through *n*, with each side being equally probably to come up in a roll, then the probability of a particular number coming up in the first roll is 1/*n*. The probability of rolling it twice is the probability of rolling it the first time, times the probability of rolling it the second time too, or (1/*n*) x (1/*n*) = 1/n<sup>2</sup>. Notice that as *n* approaches infinity, 1/n<sup>2</sup> approaches zero. So yes, in theory, the probability is zero.

Here's another interesting paradox, though. What's the probability of rolling *any* particular number on just one roll? For example, if our infinite die had its sides labeled 1, 2, 3, and so on, what's the probability of rolling "11"?  Since the probability of rolling any particular number is 1/*n*, and this approaches 0 and *n* approaches infinity, this means the probability is zero! This means that if you rolled the die and it came up to "512,345,122,667", and then calculated the probability of rolling that number, you'd get zero, despite the fact that you just saw the event happen before your eyes. This is why you have to be careful in math when dealing with infinity; it can lead to paradoxes, and we want mathematics to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

If you roll a two sided dice twice then the chance of getting the same number twice is $\frac{1}{2}$. If you roll a three sided dice twice then the change is $\frac{1}{3}$ and so if you roll a dice with n sides twice the change of getting the same number is $\frac{1}{n}$.

Now as the number n gets larger $\frac{1}{n}$ gets smaller.  If you take the limit of this to infinity (basically asking what number does this function get close to as n gets larger without bound) $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0$.  You can see that you would roll the same number twice with probability zero.

However "With probability zero" is an odd thing.  If you consider all the possible combinations of dice rolls there are clearly it is possible to happen. However all the other possibilities are so much more numerous as to crowd them out. This sort of suggests that talking about probabilities with infinite things might not be a sensible thing to do.

Answer (score -3):

A *nfr* question. Hats off to you.

We know that the probability of an event $E$ = $P(E) = \frac{n}{N}$, where the sample space = $N$ and the number of outcomes that satisfy the event $E = n$.

In this case, thanks go out to other contributors, $P(E) = \frac{1}{\infty}$.  We have the option to leave it at that i.e. your chances are $\frac{1}{\infty}$, BUT if that doesn't do it for you, we have *limits*.  Ironically, this is the *limit* of math, in its present form.

$\displaystyle \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} = 0$.

Trying these values for N, to get an idea of what the above statement is saying: $10^1, 10^{20}, 10^{50}, ...$. The value of $\frac{1}{N} \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$

The graph of $\frac{1}{N}$ is attached below. You can see that $y = 0$ (the $x$ axis) is an *asymptote*. The curve i.e. $\frac{1}{N}$ approaches it, but it never is the case that $\frac{1}{N} = 0$.

$x = N$

[image]

If you plot $\frac{1}{N}$ with a graphing calculator, and *zoom in* continuously, you'll see the graph/curve never actually hits $0$ i.e. $\frac{1}{N} \ne 0$.

This is what we'd say in the world of *pathos*, as *mixed signals*. Happens, comes with the territory, $\infty$ after all.

*Good luck*.